# Rendering css in rails 4 forms with TinyMCE

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce

I've set up TinyMCE in my rails 4 app so that input into a form can be styled. Submitting it though results in all the styles being explicitly displayed like so:

[image: css not rendering]

Not very advanced when it comes to rails here so any simple explanations of what I need to do to allow rails to render and output css correctly from forms would be great

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in the meantime, to use:

raw(...)
or 
.html_safe

Though looking around it seems these carry some security flaws.

For now though in development I've found my answer.